# A recurrence relation on two variables with indicator

Tags: recurrence-relations

I'm trying to solve an almost-simple recurrence relation:
$$
F(d,h) = F(d-1,h) +  2[d \le \alpha h] F(d-1,h-1)
$$ 
for $h \ge 2$, $d \ge 0$, provided that 
$$
 F(d,2) = \begin{cases}
d+1, &\text{ if } d \le 2\alpha \\
2\alpha + 1, &\text{ if } d > 2\alpha,
\end{cases}
$$
where $\alpha$ is a positive integer constant.

As you can see the only difficulty is the indicator $[d \le \alpha h]$. But for me it's a real pain. Please help!